# Copying multiple columns to another sheet into a single column in chronological order

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked for some pseudo code for this, but cannot find it. Any help would be appreciated. Basically I would like to take sample data  like:

```
1 A     2 B    3 C
4 D     5 E    6 F
```

and copy it to a new sheet as:

```
 1 A
 2 B
 3 C
 4 D
 5 E
 6 F
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your picture, we're copying everything in the worksheet. This will work for that case. If it's a subset, please try to modify rngSource to meet your needs:

```
Sub FlattenAndCopy()
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Excel.Range
Dim varSource As Variant
Dim wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SourceCount As Long
Dim varTarget() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set wsSource = ActiveSheet
Set rngSource = wsSource.UsedRange
varSource = rngSource.Value
SourceCount = rngSource.Cells.Count
ReDim varTarget(1 To SourceCount)
For i = LBound(varSource, 1) To UBound(varSource, 1)
    For j = LBound(varSource, 2) To UBound(varSource, 2)
        varTarget((i - 1) * (UBound(varSource, 2)) + j) = varSource(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
Set wsTarget = wsSource.Parent.Worksheets.Add
wsTarget.Cells(1).Resize(SourceCount, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varTarget)
End Sub
```